# How can I allow a SqlParameter to accept any value in SqlClient?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

I'm trying to create a generic function, using `SqlClient` in C#, which will accept a value for any column name and return the valid objects. My approach is to create a stored procedure which accepts values for every column, and where a value has not been provided it will be assume that any value is accepted. My code is as below (code is a little unfinished with regards the final requirement):

```
public async Task<List<OrganisationInstance>> GetOrganisationInstances(string name, int id)
    {
        List<OrganisationInstance> responses = new List<OrganisationInstance>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(OrganisationInstancesSP.READ_ORGANISATION, connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.Add("Id", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 2;
                    command.Parameters.Add("CreationDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "2021-12-14 23:59:25.837";
                    command.Parameters.Add("CompanyName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "xxxxxxxxxx";
                    command.Parameters.Add("Postcode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
                    command.Parameters.Add("FormationDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "2021-12-14 23:59:25.837";
                    command.Parameters.Add("NodeId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
                    SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                    while (reader.Read())
                        responses.Add(new OrganisationInstance { CompanyName = reader["CompanyName"].ToString(), Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]) });
                }
            }
            catch (DbException ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return responses;
    }
```

The query returns the expected object, when all values are set to the values of an instance/row in the database. However, I cannot find a way to set the column to allow any value.

In SQL, it would be possible to say `WHERE CreationDate = CreationDate` , which would translate to:

```
command.Parameters.Add("CreationDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "CreationDate";
```

However, this doesn't work in `SqlClient`. Can anyone suggest how I might achieve this?

Comment: You should get in the habit of **always** defining a **length** when defining a `VarChar` type parameter! So use `command.Parameters.Add("CompanyName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "xxxxxxxxxx";` to give it a suitable max length and do this for **ALL** `VarChar` parameters!

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll add that in. Normally, I will always define the VarChar length when I create the table. I hadn't thought to do that at the point of querying.

Comment: That thing you're trying to do.. [Don't](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic)

Comment: Consider that to some extent you're reinventing Dapper, and that by introducing a stored procedure you're cutting your legs off at the knees. Chuck the sproc out, dynamically form a parameterized query (with only those params supplied) in its where clause and execute it

Comment: `catch (DbException ex) { return null; }` Hiding errors is NEVER a good idea.